# The angle between a pendulum and the its base is $\alpha (t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}-\cos (\sqrt{0.98}t)$. What is the distance at $t=0$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The pitcure shows a sphere suspended by a wire with 1 meter of lenght
>   , fixed at point O.
>
> [image]
>
> The center of the sphere oscilates between A and B, which are
>   symetrical relatively to r.
>
> r goes through point O and is perpendicular to the line OS.
>
> At the initial instant, the center O of the sphere coincides with
>   point A.
>
> t seconds after that initial instant the center of the sphere is at
>   point P, such that the angle SOP in radians is given by
>
> $$\alpha (t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}-\cos (\sqrt{0.98}t)$$
>
> Determine the distance between the center of the sphere and the line
>   OS at the initial instant.
>
> Note: Don't use your calculator except for numerical calculations.

If I make a triangle XOP, with X the point that you get when you draw a straight line from P to SO, at the initial instant I get this:

[image]

So to get that distance, I would have to do $\sin(\alpha(0))$:

$$\pi/2-\pi/6-\cos(\sqrt{0.98}\cdot 0) = \pi/3-1$$

I used the calculator to make sure this was correct and I got $\sin(\pi/3-1) \approx .0472$

But my book states the solution is $\sqrt{3}/2$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you read the problem correctly? It seems odd that the problem  would say $\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{6}$ instead of simply $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @rogerl Yes, that is exactly what is says.

Comment: @rogerl My book has plenty of errors and typos making some problems unsolvable, so I wouldn't be suprised if this was the case.

Comment: That's definitely another typo, $\cos$ isn't likely to be an angle, it's a cosine.

Answer (score 1):

If the equation was $\alpha (t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}\cos (\sqrt{0.98}t)$ it would be a version of the [small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Small-angle_approximation) for a pendulum and the book's solution would be correct. The pendulum would, however, need to be on a planet with one tenth the surface gravity of Earth.